# In how may ways can we remove lines such that all dots will still be connected?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math, gap

Let there be a square, connected with 9 dots and 12 lines. We can select some lines (at least 1, maximum 4) among the 12 lines, and then remove them. 
In how may ways can we remove lines such that all dots will still be connected?

[image]

---

**Attempt:**

The number of ways of selecting lines (maximum of four lines) is: $\binom{12}{1} + \binom{12}{2} + \binom{12}{3} + \binom{12}{4}$. We can first calculate the number of ways of selecting lines such that the removal makes the dots disconnected.
Let us consider 4 cases:

- Selecting exactly one line. There is no selection of one line such that the removal makes the dots disconnected.
- Selecting exactly two lines. Notice there are only 4 selections that makes the dots disconnected, each of this is the selection of two lines connected by the corner dots. So the number of ways is
  $$ 4 $$
- Selecting exactly three lines. We can pick two lines from a corner, and one line from any of the other 10 lines. Since there are 4 corners, so it will be $10 \times 4$. Also, we can remove the 3 lines connected to a dot at the middle of a side (total of 4 sides), this will make the square disconnected. So the number of ways is
  $$ 4 + 10 \times 4$$
- Selecting exactly four lines. We find the number of ways to disconnect the dots as below: 1) Remove 1 line first that *immediately* disconnect the dots, and then pick any 3 lines. 2) Remove 2 lines first that *immediately* disconnect the dots, and then pick any 2 lines. 3) Remove 3 lines first that *immediately* disconnect the dots, and then pick any 1 line. 4) Remove 4 lines that *immediately* disconnect the dots. For case 1), we cannot pick one line that disconnect the dots. For case 2), we can select two lines at top left corner, and two more lines from the remaining 10. Similarly for the other 3 corners, this sums up to $4 \binom{10}{2} - \binom{4}{2}$. For case 3) we can remove first the three lines connected to the middle dot at the left side, plus one line from the others except lines that connected to the top left or bottom left, this means $7$. Multiply by 4 because of 4 sides. for case 4) we can remove the 4 lines connected to the center, and the square is disconnected. Finally, So the total number of selections for making the dots disconnected is:
  $$ 0 + \left( 4\binom{10}{2} - \binom{4}{2} \right) + 7 \times 4 + 1  $$

So the total number of selections for the main problem is:

$$\binom{12}{1} + \binom{12}{2} + \binom{12}{3} + \binom{12}{4} - \left( 4 + (4 + 10 \times 4)  + \left( 4\binom{10}{2} - \binom{4}{2} \right) + 7 \times 4  + 1 \right) $$

Is this correct, or are there better approaches?

Comment: There are combinations you count twice. For example your removal of 4 lines takes the two lines at the top left corner and then two of the other 10. But if the two additional lines are taken out of another corner, you will count this combination twice by repeating the procedure for the other corner. And you forgot the last parantheses in your total amount. Other than that, your approach looks fine.

Comment: @Nurator I have account that by subtraction of $\binom{4}{2}$, which is the number of pairs of corners.

Comment: You say it isn't a square any more.  Does that mean that removing one segment you must remove one of the outside segments?  Removing three lines you can also take the three bottom verticals and disconnect the diagram.  There are four like this.  I can't follow the count for removing four lines to see if I agree.

Comment: @RossMillikan I edited the question

Comment: But now you removed the $4$ from removing $3$ that comes from three to a center of a side.  You still need that.

Comment: @RossMillikan I don't see why that happens.. could you explain more..? In case 3) I said that we cannot include the corners, because it is already included in case 2)

Comment: You had correctly said that one way to disconnect the diagram was to remove the three segments that connect to the center bottom and that there are four cases like this.  I identified another set of cases that you had missed, expecting you to add them to the list.  Instead you put mine in but deleted yours.  I believe the subtraction for three is #4+4+10\times 4$

Comment: @RossMillikan You mean for the 3rd bullet point? why additional 4..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96791/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-arief-anbiya).

Comment: @RossMillikan You may post an answer if you don't mind..

Comment: By "such that all dots will still be connected" do you mean that the resulting graph is connected (i.e. each point is connected to each other point) or that there are no isolated points?

Comment: It means that the graph is still connected

Answer (score 2):

For the case of $4$ segments deleted I made use of the GAP system (tag added). I made use of the following $12 \times 9$ incidence matrix: $$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1& 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1& 0 & 0 &, 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  0& -1& 0 &, 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
the columns represent the dots and the rows the edges. I choose to use directed edges in order to easily get rid of cycles. For each of the $495$ combinations of rows I proceeded as follows:

1) First I got rid of occasional cycles by using the GAP command "BaseMat", this function removes rows that are lineraly dependent on others, so that we are left with linearly independent rows (no cycles).

2) I removed all the $-1$ by $1$ in order to make the remaining steps easier.

3) I looked for columns that had only one entry. I determined the row where this entry occured and replaced this entry with zero. In this row I localized the second entry and determined if there was another entry in its column. If this was the case then I removed the row. This has as a result that when a segment has a free endpoint but is attached to another segment it can be removed (his is what is called in homotopy theory a "retraction") .
4) I repeated step 3 until more retraction was't possible. Ending up with only one row left pointed to a connected graph, otherwis to a non connected graph.

The result gave $108$ non connected graphs as seen here [image]

The other cases can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuHX2.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuHX2.jpg), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwHF4.jpg) and [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLVaF.jpg)